# How to redefine type of window.addEventListener in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

For testing purposes, I have to mock `window.addEventListener` (with a jest empty mock is enough just to spy). So I do so like:

```
window.addEventListener = jest.fn();
window.removeEventListener = jest.fn();
```

Problem is, when I do `window.addEventListener.mockClear()` typescript complains about that method doesn't exist.

[image]

What's the best way to cope with this?

*Workaround: for now I'm doing this, but I don't like to do it all the time*

```
(window.addEventListener as jest.Mock<{}>).mockClear();
(window.addEventListener as jest.Mock<{}>).mockClear();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to augment existing interface to add some properties to methods declared in that interface.

But you can override these methods. There is a way to avoid writing type casts all the time: you can define your own `MockWindow` interface having `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` typed as you need. Then you can cast real `window` object to `MockWindow` once and use that afterwards:

```
interface MockWindow extends Window {
    addEventListener: jest.Mock<{}> & typeof window.addEventListener;
    removeEventListener: jest.Mock<{}> & typeof window.removeEventListener;
}

function mockWindow() {
    window.addEventListener = jest.fn();
    window.removeEventListener = jest.fn();
    return window as MockWindow;
}

let w = mockWindow();


w.addEventListener('load',function() {});
w.addEventListener.mockClear();
```

Actually, because in the current version of jest typings, `jest.Mock` interface already has very loose call signature

```
interface Mock<T> extends Function {
    ...
    (...args: any[]): any;
```

anything declared as `jest.Mock` can be called with any number of any parameters, and it makes adding `& typeof window.addEventListener` to the type of `addEventListener` unnecessary.

UPDATE: it turns out typescript is expressive enough so you can write generic, type-checked function:

```
function mockMethods<T, MethodName extends keyof T>(o: T, methodNames:MethodName[])
: T & {[K in MethodName]: T[K] & jest.Mock<{}>} {
    methodNames.forEach(k => {
       o[k] = jest.fn() as any;
    });
    return o as any; // typescript doesn't allow this cast: 
                     // as (T & {[K in MethodKeys]: T[K] & jest.Mock<{}>});
}

let w = mockMethods(window, ['addEventListener', 'removeEventListener']);

w.addEventListener('load', function() {});
w.addEventListener.mockClear();

// you can still call other window methods
w.alert('x');

// and their types are unaffected
w.alert.mockClear(); // error: Property 'mockClear' does not exist 
                     // on type '(message?: any) => void'.

// and you can't mock non-existent methods
let u = mockMethods(window, ['z']); // error: Argument of type '"z"[]'  
                     //  is not assignable to parameter of type '("blur" | ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very clean, concise and clear answer. Works like a charm :)